# Error 1004 - item could not be found in OLAP cube after file copied/name changed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013, powerpivot

I have a workbook which connects to data models through PowerPivot, and the resulting pivot tables are filtered based on a given array collected through a difference process.

```
Sub AccrualPivot()

'Filter the data for the accrual entries that have been made.
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myR As Range

Sheets("Tables").Activate
Sheets("Tables").Range("JournalNum1").Select
Set myR = Sheets("Tables").Range("JournalNum1")

ReDim myArray(0 To myR.Cells.Count - 1)

Sheets("Data").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AccrualPivot").PivotFields( _
    "[Query].[DataEntry].[DataEntry]").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AccrualPivot").PivotFields( _
    "[Query].[JournalNum].[JournalNum]").ClearAllFilters

For i = 0 To myR.Cells.Count - 1
    myArray(i) = "[Query].[JournalNum].&[" & myR.Cells(i + 1).Value & "]"
Next i

'ERROR THROWS HERE    
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AccrualPivot").PivotFields( _
    "[Query].[JournalNum].[JournalNum]").VisibleItemsList = myArray

'This filters out the Data entries, which need to be included in a separate pivot.
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AccrualPivot").PivotFields( _
    "[Query].[DataEntry].[DataEntry]").CurrentPageName = _
    "[Query].[DataEntry].&[0]"
End Sub
```

The error on the indicated line:

> Run-time error '1004': The item could not be found in the OLAP cube.

When I put a watch on this line, both expressions are Variants and myArray has populated with the necessary information. The kicker (and I'm assuming the root) is that **this works in my original file.** But I need to be able to Save As the workbook to roll over for each month.

I need a file for 4.30, 5.31, etc. If I save the workbook as the following month, change the dates and run everything, it works. But if I close that file, reopen and try to run, I get the 1004 error.

Nowhere in the module do I reference the file name or file path. They're even saved in the same path, just as separate months, and all the sheets are named the same. I'm assuming it's embedded somewhere that I can't find.

Comment: Try a worksheet variable instead of ActiveSheet.

Comment: I also have this problem. It seems like Excel has some bugs in it when linking to OLAP cubes. It doesn't seem to be able to reliably set the CurrentPageName programatically. Which is weird because it must be running the same code when you drop a filter for the field into the pivot table. Any luck solving Sarah?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but fiddling with the variable `UpdateStr` made it work.
There is probably a cleaner way of doing this, but... it worked for me!

```
Sub FormatTables()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim UpdateStr As String
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
       Set MySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
       If Left(MySheet.name, 7) = "looking for specific sheet names to modify the pivots" Then
          For Each pt In MySheet.PivotTables
             For Each pf In pt.PivotFields

' I am looping through all fields as I'm doing multiple pivot filtering, and setting different fields to other values... but in this example I only include one field.

                If pf.Caption = "CoverageYear" Then
                   With pf
                      .ClearAllFilters
                      UpdateStr = Left(pf.Value, InStrRev(pf.Value, ".")) & "&[2019]"
                      .CurrentPageName = UpdateStr
                   End With
                End If
             Next
             pt.RefreshTable
          Next
       End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this error and found [Delora Bradish](https://www.delorabradish.com/ssas/excel-error-the-item-could-not-be-found-in-the-olap-cube) helpful: Rebuild the data model and run the code again.

The powerquery data model is fragile and there are unpredictable consequences when a table is renamed. Also, if you are scripting the model build, the order in which tables are added matters; though tables can be added simultaneously (multi-core processing), and it usually works just fine, sometimes the resulting model misses a table reference somewhere and you get this error. Change the load order to ensure good separation of the big files.

If you are using powerquery, you should have a plan for clean rebuilds of your data model from time to time.